# Asyncio function inside a thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, cryptofeed

The *cryptofeed* is a python library that uses asyncio library to get real-time prices of different Crypto Exchanges.
In this short program, we try to run the cryptofeed FeedHandler in an independent thread. An example of the code is shown below:

```
import functools as fct
from cryptofeed import FeedHandler
from cryptofeed.defines import BID, ASK, L2_BOOK
from cryptofeed.exchanges import Kraken
from datetime import datetime
import threading


async def bookfunc(params , orderbooks, feed, symbol, book, timestamp, receipt_timestamp):

    print(f'Timestamp: {timestamp} Cryptofeed Receipt: {receipt_timestamp} Feed: {feed} Symbol: {symbol}'
          f' Book Bid Size is {len(book[BID])} Ask Size is {len(book[ASK])}')
    orderbooks = filter_orderbook(orderbooks, book, symbol, params['orderbook']['depth'])


def func():

    # Parameters
    params = {'orderbook': {'depth': 2}, 'price_model':{}, 'trade_model': {}}
    config = {'log': {'filename': 'logs/demo.log', 'level': 'INFO'}}

    orderbooks = {}

    f = FeedHandler(config=config)
    f.add_feed(Kraken(checksum_validation=True, subscription={L2_BOOK: ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', 'LINK-USD', 'LTC-USD', 'ADA-USD']},
                      callbacks={L2_BOOK: fct.partial(bookfunc, params, orderbooks)})) # This way passes the orderbooks inside the callback

    f.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=())
    thread.start()
```

When the code is executed, the get the following error:

```
raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

**EDIT**:
This is the solution for different questions in stackoverflow. An example is the following Question:

[Running cryptofeed (asyncio library) in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699836/running-cryptofeed-asyncio-library-in-a-new-thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As of `cryptofeed==1.9.2`) there are two important things to make it run from a thread:

1. `FeedHandler.run` sets up signal handlers by default, which [must
   be done from the main thread](https://github.com/bmoscon/cryptofeed/blob/eaa49906/cryptofeed/feedhandler.py#L37). To avoid that, there's
   `install_signal_handlers` argument on the method.
2. Initialiser of `FeedHandler` [set's `uvloop`'s policy](https://github.com/bmoscon/cryptofeed/blob/eaa49906/cryptofeed/feedhandler.py#L73), but
   doesn't call `uvloop.install()` (assuming it's the application's
   responsibility I guess). Without it `asyncio.set_event_loop`
   doesn't have effect. Alternatively you can set `'uvloop': False`
   in the feed handler config (as shown below), or just uninstall
   `uvloop`.

```py
import asyncio
import threading

from cryptofeed import FeedHandler
from cryptofeed.defines import BID, ASK, L2_BOOK
from cryptofeed.exchanges import Kraken


async def bookfunc(**kwargs):
    print('bookfunc', kwargs)
    

def run_feed_handler_forever():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    
    config = {
        'uvloop': False,
        'log': {'filename': 'log.log', 'level': 'DEBUG'},
    }
    l2_book = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', 'LINK-USD', 'LTC-USD', 'ADA-USD']
    feed = Kraken(
        subscription={L2_BOOK: l2_book}, callbacks={L2_BOOK: bookfunc}
    )
    fh = FeedHandler(config)
    fh.add_feed(feed)
    fh.run(install_signal_handlers=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_feed_handler_forever)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually set an event **loop** for your thread through `asyncio`. You can do it by wrapping your function in a sort of loop setter:

```
def create_loop(func):
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   loop.run_until_complete(func())
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = threading.Thread(target=create_loop, args=(func,))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: It is a good hint, I will search a little bit more about this. The code that you post doesn't work.

Comment: After some work, I found that you're right. However I still have the following message: raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'. Do you know why?

Comment: @nunodsousa From source it seems that `set_event_loop()` is not executed if the current thread is not the main thread. This is simply the default loop policy of asyncio. One could define it's own policy class to make that method support any thread event. Or you can just use the asyncio integration from tornado (`tornado.platform.asyncio`) that already defines that policy and allows you to manually enable it: `asyncio.asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy())`